# Checking how much times a character occurs in a string with a recursive function

Tags: c

So, I have to write down a recursive function for checking how much times a character (c) occurs in a string (array) : note that the function MUST BE recursive. To be honest this is the hardest thing I've had to face since I started, so this is taking very long :| Here is the code (language is C) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 5

int charOccur (char [], int);

int main() {

char array[MAX+1]={'a', 'x', 'c', 'f', 'r'};

charOccur (array, MAX);

return 0;
}

int charOccur (char arr[], int dim){
int i, flag=0;

    if (arr[0] == 'c'){
        flag = 1;
        return flag;
    } else {
        for (i=1; i<dim; i++){
            if (arr[i] == 'c'){
                flag++;
                charOccur (arr, dim);
            }
        } return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: the whole idea for using recursion for this problem is that you dont need to use a for loop. Try to create a function that has: 1. a base case of an empty string and 2. a recursive call of the string without its first character. Fill in the gaps to that logic with what you are trying to achieve and I think you'll find that you dont need a for loop

Comment: This is an excellent time to learn how to use a debugger, and how to use it to step through your code line by line. Doing that will show you exactly what the program does and what the values of all variables are. Doing that, and stepping into the recursive calls, will probably be very enlightening.

Comment: @RNar, actually this is not the first recursive function I use, but I only did code for maths function, something like calculating n element of Fibonacci's sequence or calculating a factorial number, so I'm actually having trouble thinking about non-math things (hope you get it), and also I don't get the base case. Why should the string be empty?

Comment: By the way, with a little trickery [the function can be implemented using only three lines of code](http://ideone.com/jXZclR).

Answer (score 1):

You should read a bit on memoization (it's not a typo). This [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is a good starting point; a more practical example is [this one](http://rayhightower.com/blog/2014/04/12/recursion-and-memoization/), which says:

> Memoization means recording the results of earlier calculations so that we don’t have to repeat the calculations later.

In other words, in your code you might consider passing a counter to your function to store the result of the computation, before passing it to itself for the next recursion.

The example is shown in Ruby - it will help you understand the concept, rather than copy-pasting it as a solution.

And don't forget that in order to understand recursion, [you must first understand recursion.](http://www.cbsnews.com/pictures/17-amazing-google-easter-eggs/17/)

Comment: Your second link, for the example, is broken. Just FYI so you can fix it. And it might just be better to add the code example directly in your answer in this case.

Comment: @gmiley thanks for the link fix. I did not want to put the code example here as I think it requires the context of the original page, and I wanted to encourage the OP to do a bit of research and reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
int occur(char *s, char c)
{
    if (!*s) // if (*s == '\0')
        return (0); // s is empty, do the character we're looking for does not exist
    else if (*s == c)
        return (1 + occur(s + 1, c));
    else
        return (occur(s + 1, c));
}
```

In the second case, we found our character, so we count 1 plus the rest of the input fed in our recursive function.

In the third case, the character pointed by s is neither '\0' nor c, so we keep going until we reach the end of the string.

In boths case, we use pointer arithmetic (s + 1), to change the character which is being pointed.

Comment: can you explain me why the condition (!*s) is equal to (*s == '\0') ?

Comment: @Simone The condition (cond) is equivalent to (s != 0). By deferencing the pointer s, we look at the character pointed by s, *s. So the condition (*s) is true if (*s != 0), so the negation becomes true if (*s == 0), or (*s == '\0') because the value of '\0' in the ascii table is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a recursion that divides by 2 in each call.  It does not reduce the number of calls, but limits the call depth to O(log2(n)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static size_t Occurrence_helper(const char *s, size_t length, int ch) {
  if (length > 1) {
    size_t left = length / 2;
    size_t right = length - left;
    return Occurrence_helper(s, left, ch)
        + Occurrence_helper(s + left, right, ch);
  } else if (length > 0) {
    return *s == ch;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

size_t Occurrence(const char *s, int ch) {
  return Occurrence_helper(s, strlen(s), ch);
}
```

Sample

```
int main(void) {
  int ch = 'y';
  const char *s = "xyzzy";
  printf("'%c' occurs %zu times in \"%s\".\n", ch, Occurrence(s, ch), s);
  return 0;
}

// Ouptut
'y' occurs 2 times in "xyzzy".
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 01 ) where 'c' is a constant
int charOccur (char arr[], int dim){
    if(!dim) return 0;
    dim--;
    return ('c'==arr[dim])+charOccur (arr,dim);
}

// 02 ) passing c as a second parameter
int charOccur (char arr[],char c , int dim){
    if(!dim) return 0;
    dim--;
    return (c==arr[dim])+charOccur (arr,c,dim);
}
```